# Obtain id of UL closest to the button that was clicked

Tags: jquery

How do I get the id of a ul that is closest to the button that was clicked using jquery? The button in the second group seems to be returning my top-most ul. Thanks.

```
 div class="First">
    <ul id="One">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
     <button type="button"  id="4444" onclick="GetClosestUl()">Get Closest Ul to button</button>
</div>
<div class="First">
    <ul id="Two">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
     <button type="button"  id="5555" onclick="GetClosestUl()">Get Closest Ul to button</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GetClosestUl() {
    console.log($("button").closest() + "   this is ul id");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mbd91Lw/2/). You should also take a look at the api documentation for `.closest` [here.](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
You were on the right track of calling a function on the click of the button, but your implementation of the `closest` method was wrong. What i did above was to bind the click event (e) and then use jQuery to get the target element of the event (e) and then use the `closest` method in the intended manor.

Comment: Thanks. I was way off.

Comment: This might answer the question but please provide more details and the key part of the solution inside here, not only as a link.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out @Markus. I have edited my answer.